# geoJSON to Table not showing up on webpage

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I initially asked this question in SO but thought it might be more relevant here since I'm using geoJSON.

I have a geoJSON file with a couple of thousand records that I want grouped and presented on a webpage. I tried using this plugin to create a summary table of the data: http://afshinm.github.io/Json-to-HTML-Table/

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Mountain View Residential Garbage - Tuesday</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" type="text/css" crossorigin="">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js" crossorigin=""></script>
      <script src="ResGarbThursLines.js"></script>
      <script src="json-to-table.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style6.css" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript">

  function loadJSON(path, success, error){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ //should partheses be closed here?
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          if (success)
             success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
          } else {
              if (error)
                error(xhr);
          }
      }
};

    xhr.open("GET", path, true);

    xhr.send();

}
          var map;
          var routeNum = new Array();
          var routeSummary = new Array();

          function init() {


          loadJSON('ResGarbThursLines.geojson', function(data) { 
            var joinToTable = ConvertJsonToTable(data, 'jsonTable');
            console.log(typeof data); 
          },
          function(xhr) { console.error(xhr); 
          }

          );

          // create map and set center and zoom level
          map = new L.map('mapid');
          map.setView([37.393807,-122.068598],14);

             // Add the tiled layer       
            var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: "Data copyright OpenStreetMap contributors"});
            tiles.addTo(map);

          var resGarbThursLayer;
          var selection
          var selectedLayer

          function thursStyle(feature){
            for (r in routeNum) {
              //console.log (routeNum[r]);
            }
            switch (feature.properties.Route){
              case '01X':
                return {
                    "color": "red",
                    "weight": 5,
                    "opacity": 0.65
                    };
                  break;
              case '02X':
                return {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "weight": 5,
                    "opacity": 0.65
                    };
                  break;
            case '03X':
                return {
                    "color": "green",
                    "weight": 5,
                    "opacity": 0.65
                    };
                  break;
              case '04X':
              return {
                    "color": "purple",
                    "weight": 5,
                    "opacity": 0.65
                    };
                  break;
              case '05X':
              return {
                    "color": "orange",
                    "weight": 5,
                    "opacity": 0.65
                    };
                }
            }

          function thursSelectedStyle(feature){
            return {
            "color": "#00FFFF",
            "weight": 9,
            "opacity": 0.95
          };
        }

          // handle click events on pantry features
          function thursOnEachFeature(feature, layer){
       // create an array for all route numbers
             routeNum.push(feature.properties.Route);
            layer.on({
              click: function(e) {
                  if (selection) {
                    resetStyles();
                  }
                  e.target.setStyle(thursSelectedStyle());
                  selection = e.target;
                  selectedLayer = resGarbThursLayer;

                  // Insert some HTML with the feature name
                  buildSummaryLabel(feature);

                  L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e); // stop click event from being propagated further
                }
            });
          }

          // add the gardens GeoJSON layer using the pantriesData variable from pantries.js
                resGarbThursLayer = new L.geoJSON(thursdayData,{ style: thursStyle, onEachFeature: thursOnEachFeature}).addTo(map);


          // handle clicks on the map that didn't hit a feature
          map.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if (selection) {
              resetStyles();
              selection = null;
              document.getElementById('summaryLabel').innerHTML = '<p>Click a line to get the sum of weight, service time, and stop numbers for that block.</p>';
            }
          });

          // function to set the old selected feature back to its original symbol. Used when the map or a feature is clicked.
          function resetStyles(){
            if (selectedLayer === resGarbThursLayer) selectedLayer.resetStyle(selection);
          }

          // function to build the HTML for the summary label using the selected feature's "name" property
          function buildSummaryLabel(currentFeature){
            var Count = currentFeature.properties.COUNT_Ref_ || "Unnamed feature";
            var Demand = currentFeature.properties.SUM_Demand || "Unnamed feature";
            var Time = currentFeature.properties.SUM_Servic || "Unnamed feature";
            document.getElementById('summaryLabel').innerHTML = '<p style="font-size:18px"><b>' + "Stops: " + Count + '<br>' + "Tons: " + Demand + '<br>' + "Service time: " + Time + '</b></p>';
          }

        }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init()">
        <h1 id="title">Thursday Residential Garbage</h1>

        <div id="mapid"></div>
        <div id="summaryLabel">
            <p>Click on a line to get more info.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tableid">
        <table id='jsonTable'></table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/**
 * Basic Typography
 */
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #222;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 1em 1.5em;
}
pre, code {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    white-space: pre;
}
pre, code {
    font: 1em 'andale mono', 'lucida console', monospace;
    line-height:1.5;
}
a[href] {
    color: #436976;
    background-color: transparent;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #003a6b;
    background-color: transparent;
    font: 100% 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Geneva, Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 130%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fcb100;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.olControlAttribution {
    bottom: 5px;
}

/**
 * Map Examples Specific
 */
.smallmap {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 1024px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tags {
    display: none;
}

#docs p {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#mapid {
    height : 500px !important;
    width:75%;
}
#tableid {
    height : 250px ;
    width : 25%;
    position : relative;
}
/* mobile specific */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        height           : 100%;
        margin           : 0;
        padding          : 0;
        width            : 100%;
    }
    #map {
        background : #7391ad;
        width      : 100%;
    }
    #map {
        border : 0;
        height : 250px;
    }
    #title {
        font-size   : 1.3em;
        line-height : 2em;
        text-indent : 1em;
        margin      : 0;
        padding     : 0;
    }
    #docs {
        bottom     : 0;
        padding    : 1em;
    }
    #shortdesc {
        color      : #aaa;
        font-size  : 0.8em;
        padding    : 1em;
        text-align : right;
    }
    #tags {
        display : none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 600px) {
    #shortdesc {
       float: right;
       width: 25%;
    }
    #map {
        width: 70%;
    }
    #docs {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Here is the first bit of the geoJSON (referenced as "ResGarbThursLines.js" file in the html):

```
var thursdayData = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "Street_ID": 887932285.0, "Route": "03X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.044, "SUM_Servic": 1.2, "COUNT_Ref_": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.05675789199995, 37.405177089000063 ], [ -122.05864249499996, 37.405582278000054 ], [ -122.05930716899996, 37.405727143000036 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 2, "Street_ID": 23694678.0, "Route": "03X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.143, "SUM_Servic": 3.9, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.06109679499997, 37.402789313000028 ], [ -122.06099837899995, 37.403160261000039 ], [ -122.06095929699995, 37.403599941000039 ], [ -122.06096881599996, 37.403704653000034 ], [ -122.06096893755976, 37.403713777598547 ], [ -122.06096765199999, 37.403722812000069 ], [ -122.06094765199998, 37.403812812000069 ], [ -122.06094513089909, 37.40382117773111 ], [ -122.06094140312075, 37.40382907995069 ], [ -122.06093655025629, 37.403836345699929 ], [ -122.06093067852217, 37.403842815950632 ], [ -122.06092391643529, 37.403848349085955 ], [ -122.06091641199998, 37.403852824000069 ], [ -122.06085641199996, 37.40388282400005 ], [ -122.06084796575122, 37.403886260115591 ], [ -122.06083909123346, 37.403888355095837 ], [ -122.06083, 37.403889059000051 ], [ -122.06074, 37.403889059000051 ], [ -122.06073484835773, 37.403888833758145 ], [ -122.06072973599998, 37.403888160000065 ], [ -122.06067605599998, 37.403878687000031 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 3, "Street_ID": 23694678.0, "Route": "03X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.143, "SUM_Servic": 3.9, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.06098262699999, 37.402759023000044 ], [ -122.06088291599997, 37.403134855000076 ], [ -122.06088117299998, 37.403144771000029 ], [ -122.06084117299997, 37.40359477100003 ], [ -122.0608409412845, 37.40360005924677 ], [ -122.06084118399997, 37.403605347000052 ], [ -122.06085035, 37.403706177000061 ], [ -122.06083844599999, 37.403759748000027 ], [ -122.06081605799994, 37.403770941000062 ], [ -122.06074517099995, 37.403770941000062 ], [ -122.06069658399997, 37.40376236700007 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 4, "Street_ID": 23694694.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.033, "SUM_Servic": 0.9, "COUNT_Ref_": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07683047899997, 37.388541716000077 ], [ -122.07676108499999, 37.388658588000055 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 5, "Street_ID": 23694694.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.033, "SUM_Servic": 0.9, "COUNT_Ref_": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07672891499999, 37.388481412000033 ], [ -122.07665952099995, 37.388598284000068 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 6, "Street_ID": 23694696.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07663804399999, 37.388861517000066 ], [ -122.07637238799998, 37.389290655000025 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 7, "Street_ID": 23694696.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07653761199998, 37.388799345000052 ], [ -122.07627195599997, 37.389228483000068 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 8, "Street_ID": 23694697.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.121, "SUM_Servic": 3.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07743772099997, 37.387561487000028 ], [ -122.07695255699997, 37.388340931000073 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 9, "Street_ID": 23694697.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.121, "SUM_Servic": 3.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07733744299998, 37.387499069000057 ], [ -122.07685227899998, 37.388278513000046 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 10, "Street_ID": 23694698.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.132, "SUM_Servic": 3.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 12 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07815685899999, 37.386421404000032 ], [ -122.07756300699998, 37.387361670000075 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 11, "Street_ID": 23694698.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.132, "SUM_Servic": 3.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 12 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07805699299996, 37.386358330000064 ], [ -122.07746314099995, 37.387298596000051 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 12, "Street_ID": 23695432.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.044, "SUM_Servic": 1.2, "COUNT_Ref_": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07459079899996, 37.381326838000064 ], [ -122.07381605099999, 37.382320536000066 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 13, "Street_ID": 23696915.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.132, "SUM_Servic": 3.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07640559199996, 37.391391270000042 ], [ -122.07573366199995, 37.392432764000034 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 14, "Street_ID": 23696915.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.132, "SUM_Servic": 3.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07630633799999, 37.391327236000052 ], [ -122.07563440799998, 37.392368730000044 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 15, "Street_ID": 23696917.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.066, "SUM_Servic": 1.8, "COUNT_Ref_": 6 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07693960699999, 37.390531649000025 ], [ -122.07662155499997, 37.391059325000072 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 16, "Street_ID": 23696917.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.066, "SUM_Servic": 1.8, "COUNT_Ref_": 6 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07683844499996, 37.390470675000074 ], [ -122.07652039299995, 37.390998351000064 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 17, "Street_ID": 23696918.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.033, "SUM_Servic": 0.9, "COUNT_Ref_": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07718597599995, 37.390141312000026 ], [ -122.07706346399999, 37.390332432000037 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 18, "Street_ID": 23696919.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.011, "SUM_Servic": 0.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07723731599998, 37.389838862000033 ], [ -122.07721252, 37.389878536000026 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 19, "Street_ID": 23696920.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.11, "SUM_Servic": 3.0, "COUNT_Ref_": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07788297399998, 37.388951872000064 ], [ -122.07745971399999, 37.389696498000035 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 20, "Street_ID": 23696920.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.11, "SUM_Servic": 3.0, "COUNT_Ref_": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07778028599995, 37.38889350200003 ], [ -122.07735702599996, 37.389638128000058 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 21, "Street_ID": 23696923.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07946072399994, 37.386194151000041 ], [ -122.07920624399998, 37.386648089000062 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 22, "Street_ID": 23696924.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.011, "SUM_Servic": 0.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07985683, 37.385558060000051 ], [ -122.07958345399999, 37.385988628000064 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 23, "Street_ID": 23696925.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.08023741799997, 37.384949028000051 ], [ -122.07998232599999, 37.385358518000032 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 24, "Street_ID": 23697067.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07405839299997, 37.387831549000055 ], [ -122.07396263, 37.387987162000059 ], [ -122.07387049899995, 37.388204328000029 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 25, "Street_ID": 23697067.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07395779699999, 37.38776964300007 ], [ -122.07385737, 37.38793283800004 ], [ -122.07376176299999, 37.388158198000042 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 26, "Street_ID": 23697069.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07493889199998, 37.386581590000048 ], [ -122.07470193799998, 37.386969932000056 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 27, "Street_ID": 23697069.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07483806199997, 37.386520068000038 ], [ -122.07460110799997, 37.386908410000046 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 28, "Street_ID": 23697070.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.022, "SUM_Servic": 0.6, "COUNT_Ref_": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07520012, 37.385893253000063 ], [ -122.07495732599995, 37.386318145000075 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 29, "Street_ID": 23697072.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.044, "SUM_Servic": 1.2, "COUNT_Ref_": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07577254699999, 37.385210900000061 ], [ -122.07552519299998, 37.385575422000045 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 30, "Street_ID": 23697073.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.121, "SUM_Servic": 3.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07665444, 37.384009562000074 ], [ -122.07591024299995, 37.38497157200004 ], [ -122.07589564799997, 37.38500076400004 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 31, "Street_ID": 23697073.0, "Route": "05X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.121, "SUM_Servic": 3.3, "COUNT_Ref_": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07656101399999, 37.383937290000063 ], [ -122.07581328699996, 37.38490386400008 ], [ -122.07580999452529, 37.384908577589819 ], [ -122.07580717599996, 37.384913589000064 ], [ -122.07579, 37.384947942000053 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 32, "Street_ID": 23697166.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.066, "SUM_Servic": 1.8, "COUNT_Ref_": 5 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07733146899994, 37.389997528000038 ], [ -122.07817114099998, 37.390322308000066 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 33, "Street_ID": 23697166.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "R", "SUM_Demand": 0.066, "SUM_Servic": 1.8, "COUNT_Ref_": 5 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07728885899996, 37.390107692000072 ], [ -122.07812853099995, 37.390432472000043 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 34, "Street_ID": 23697167.0, "Route": "04X", "Side": "L", "SUM_Demand": 0.044, "SUM_Servic": 1.2, "COUNT_Ref_": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -122.07839158699994, 37.390408840000077 ], [ -122.07935212099994, 37.390791426000078 ] ] } }
]}
```

JSON to table file won't fit on this post but can be found at the link in the beginning of the post.

The page loads but the summary table doesn't show up. I used console log to return the object type of the variable data and it is in fact an object. No errors coming up in the console.

Is there a better option for displaying summarized geoJSON data on a webpage or is there something that I'm missing with the plug in above?

Comment: your HTML <table> id is *jsonTab**e**le*...

Comment: @ThingumaBob oops! shanged it to jsonTable but still no table

Comment: hehe...okay, then try not to stringify the json when passing to the function? looks like it wants the json object itself

Comment: @ThingumaBob still nothing

Comment: check your json object (*console.log(data)*), does it have your data? check if the table exists in the DOM and if it's position, dimensions and colors/opacity make sense.

Comment: @ThingumaBob console log returns object. Will look at DOM.

Comment: @ThingumaBob DOM is good. At this point I'm looking for another plug in. Something with higher use and documentation.

Comment: this is essentially impossible without functional example, can you post a full version somewhere and then share it?

Comment: @albert this is a proof of concept running on localhost. Do you just need the entire html file or that and the css and geoJSON files?

Comment: @ShaunO all of it necessary to duplicate exactly what you have.

Comment: @albert I added the complete html and css files as well as the first bit of geoJSON

Comment: @ShaunO cool, but that's not all of it. aside from not the full .geojson file, the other scripts on the page are omitted, so there is now way to get a full picture of what is going on. also ask for functional example, because i do want to help, but i don't want to waste time setting up a sandbox to help. i just spent 20+ minutes looking at that horrible example on that repo, and now i'm giving up. not trying to be rude about it, my point is, happy to give you more than 20. not going to waste time trying to get there. if you manage to throw up a version, share the url.

Comment: change the id on your wrapper div. still not sure what is going on, but the convert function accepts tableId, it is tableid, maybe just name collision.

Comment: @albert thanks for your help. Changed tableid to tableId and still nu sum table. I'm shifting to using a javascript function like in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199653/javascript-sum-and-group-by-of-json-data. I couldn't find a functional sample with the old code.

Comment: sorry, functional is a little misleading in this case; all we need is an exact replica, or living instance, of the code that you need help on. there's no way to debug/recreate environments without all of the parts of the original one. if you go with your current choice, good luck. if you want to post what you have, i'm more than happy to look.